# How to set IsItemsHost in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

In WPF Panel.IsItemsHost is set-get property. In Silverlight - get only, why I can simulate this in Silverlight?
Using in WPF code:

```
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
     <Setter.Value>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: What is your reason for doing this?

Answer (score 4):

It was necessary in a previous version of Silverlight to set `IsItemsHost="True"` for a panel in an `ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate`.

Now the Silverlight controls library fortunately can discover that automatically. One could think that was a no-brainer actually anyway. :->

I don't know if/when WPF will adapt that behavior as well.

Answer (score 0):

Question closed. In ItemsPanelTemplate not neccesary using IsItemHost.